# Follow Twitter Users by Submitting Username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

Rails 3.2, Twitter App

SOLUTION SEE: [Can't unfollow user because of Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849336/cant-unfollow-user-because-of-postgres)

The goal is a form that will go something like this.

`username => User => User.id => followed_id => following? => New or Destroy Relationship`

Here's what I have to follow twitter users at the moment.

`views/users/buddies.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @relationship do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :followed_id %>
<%= f.submit "Add" %>
```

`users_controller.rb`

```
def buddies
@relationship =Relationship.new(params[:followed_id])
```

`relationships_controller.rb`

```
    def create
    @relationship = Relationship.new(params[:relationship])
    @relationship.follower_id = current_user.id

    if @relationship.save
        redirect_to buddies_path, notice: "Phriend added"
        else
        flash[:error] = "Phriend not added";
        redirect_to buddies_path
    end
```

`relationship.rb`

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :followed_id, :follower_id
   belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
   belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
   validates :followed_id, presence: true
   validates :follower_id, presence: true
```

`user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :follower_relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "followed_id"
  has_many :followed_relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "follower_id" 
  has_many :followers, through: :follower_relationships
  has_many :followeds, through: :followed_relationships
```

So what that does is:

I have 4 users: 1: benben, 2:nicknick, 3:stevesteve, 4:petepete

Those are their user_ids. Which are also their follower/ed ids.

Benben can type in "2", and follow "nicknick" etc..

I would like a system where I can Follow and Unfollow by submitting the username.

So I imagined something like this..

`users_controller.rb`

```
  @user = User.find(params[:username])
      if @user
        if current_user.following? @user.id
          Relationship.new(params[:followed_id])
        else
          Relationship.destroy(params[:followed_id])
        end
      end
```

`user.rb`

```
def following? user
self.followeds.include? user
end
```

What do you think will work?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is ensure that you are getting the correct user that you want to associate with.

It should not matter if you are searching by id or by name. If you have the active record for that user you can easily associate by just connecting the objects.

```
#find by whatever params float your boat
@user = User.find(params[:user])
#add the user to the list of followers
current_user.followers << @user
current_user.save

#or you could delete
@lame_follower = current_user.followers.find(1)
@lame_follower.destroy
```

Comment: btw your naming conventions bothered me too much to try to follow. But if you need more clarification or I just missed your question let me know.

Comment: So it might come off that I know more than i actually do. In this app I'm breaking a lot of rules, so I have a feeling this will not work. I get couldn't find user without an ID a lot.

Comment: No worries man. Thats why we are here (to learn :D). In response to your couldn't find user without an ID. Are you checking printing anything to the logs to see why this might be happening? Try to use logger.debug(@user.inspect). I'd be curious if you gain any insight from that.

Comment: Oh man get ready or your mind to be blown. You should typically be putting logger code in the controller as most of your logic for the application should live there.

Comment: My mind wasn't blown yet, but i figured it out! Almost, I can follow users by username, but when i try to unfollow, i get this... `Unknown key: follower_id app/models/user.rb:34:in unfollow
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:21:in buddies `

Comment: which is weird because my follow method is the same exact thing.. it must be a problem in my relationship.destroy controller?

Comment: making progress... `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "id"
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "relationships" WHERE "id"."follower_id" = 3 AND...
                                          ^
: DELETE FROM "relationships" WHERE "id"."follower_id" = 3 AND "id"."followed_id" = 2`

Comment: sounds like there is an issue with your lookup method. There seems to be something wrong with your associations.

Comment: the id is blank, how can i fill that in automagically? I've tried everything.

Comment: is the id blank in some submission form? or just when you are running the active record query? if its a form just use a hidden field and set it there

Comment: I fixed it don't worry.

Comment: alright so do you know what your original problem was? if my answer put you in the right direction just confirm it. or i can update it to help others in the future