# Can't unfollow user because of Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, twitter

Rails 3.2, Twitter App

UPDATE: Sovled but any idea why it might work once, then when i try it again, I get `Unknown key: #<User:0x007f9a5a946708>` On line 16 `users_controller.rb` for @user. If i update a status or re-login its fine.

SOLUTION: After adding a `notice: "Added", redirect_to_path` under each if/else it worked fine. I haven't been able to produce an error for "user not found" tho.

I got a `form_for`, I type in `:username`, it follows or unfollows. Unfollow don't work. Looks like this.

`Error`

`PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "id"
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "relationships" WHERE "id"."follower_id" = 1 AND...
                                          ^
: DELETE FROM "relationships" WHERE "id"."follower_id" = 1 AND "id"."followed_id" = 2`

id is missing? So I think the problem is in `relationship_controller.rb`

`/users/buddies.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for :username, :url => {:action => :buddies} do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field @user, placeholder: "username" %>
<%= f.submit "Add/Subtract" %>
<% end %>
```

`users_controller.rb`

```
@user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])

            if @user
                unless @user.blank?
                if current_user.following? @user
                    current_user.unfollow @user
                  else
                    current_user.follow @user
                end
              else
                flash[:error] = "stupid error";
                end
            end
```

`user.rb`

```
  def following? user
   self.followeds.include? user
  end

  def follow user
    Relationship.create follower_id: self.id, followed_id: user.id
  end

 def unfollow user
   Relationship.delete follower_id: self.id, followed_id: user.id
 end
```

`relationships_controller.rb`

```
def create

    @relationship = Relationship.new(params[:relationship]) 
    #@relationship.followed_id = params[:followed_id]
    @relationship.follower_id = current_user.id

    if @relationship.save
        redirect_to buddies_path, notice: "Phriend added"
        else
        flash[:error] = "Phriend not added";
        redirect_to buddies_path
    end
end

def delete
    @relationship = Relationship.find(params[:id])
    @relationship.delete
    redirect_to buddies_path, notice: "Phriend subtracted"
end
```

So that's a lot of words, but look in Relationship.delete.. what needs to change there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relationship.delete is expecting an id. Try something like:

```
# app/models/user.rb
def unfollow user
  Relationship.where(:follower_id => self.id, :followed_id => user.id).first.delete
end
```

Or, perhaps a bit clearer, if followeds are relationships:

```
def unfollow user
  self.followeds.where(:followed_id => user.id).first.delete
end
#didn't work for @ladiesman217
```

Comment: Yeah you nailed it. But add your colons! Then it worked. I used the first one. Second one didn't work so hot. THANK YOU.

Comment: Glad it worked. Arg. I was switching between `followed: user.id` and `:followed => user.id` syntax. Good catch. Also, I see that followeds isn't actually an association but a collection. Glad you found a solution.

Comment: You don't have to, but can you diagnose my new error at the top here? It seems to happen if follow/unfollow twice in a row.

Comment: For your flash message, it will depend on whether or not you're redirecting on error. If you're just rendering, use `flash.now[:error] = 'stupid error'`. That will populate the flash error for immediate use. As for the other error, it looks like you're passing an instance of a model (user) when it should perhaps be a symbol or string, depending on what's having the issue. I don't know what's on line 16 and surrounding it. BTW, have you looked at [this twitter clone tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-ribbit-in-rails/) for ideas?

Comment: That tutorial is what i copied :P I'm building something slightly different. I also solved the problem, I just had to add a `notice/redirect` line under my each .follow .unfollow in my `if` statement.